# Get cell range through getting cell addresses with formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a formula that will allow me to count a number of lines used between a cell range. I created a test formula to see if my thought process was straight. For my test I put a header called "NUM" (`A1`) and then on the same column a bunch of rows of "1"'s then another header beneath the first array called "NUM2" (`column A` but could be anywhere) with more "1"'s under that as well. I'm using a formula to find the cell address to find the first header which is

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,MATCH("NUM",A:A,0),1))
```

which printed (`$A$1`) and then combining it with

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,MATCH("NUM2",A:A,0),1))
```

which printed (`$A$14`) to get the second header name, after that I'm using a `COUNTIF` function to count the ones like so:

```
 =COUNTIF((CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,MATCH("NUM",A:A,0),1)))&":"& CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,MATCH("NUM2",A:A,0),1))),"1"))
```

and I thought that if I didn't use the formulas inside the formulas it would look like:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$14,"1")
```

which prints my desired number of 12. My question is can I not put the combination of the two formulas inside of the bigger `COUNTIF` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing an [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) which will turn your string into a cell reference.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,MATCH("NUM",A:A,0),1)) & ":" & CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,MATCH("NUM2",A:A,0),1))),1)
```

A simpler version (assuming column A) would be

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("NUM",A:A,0)&":A"&MATCH("NUM2",A:A,0)),1)
```

You could also use OFFSET.